# Как выйти из программы в C++ с помощью клавиши ESC

Tags: c++

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии клавиши ESC, без нажатия затем клавиши Enter, в getchar(е) например, программа завершалась?

Comment: Нужно анализировать нажатые клавиши. Если нажата клавиша ESC, то выходить из программы.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `_getch()` из `conio.h`

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <conio.h>
if (_getch() == 27)
{
    exit(0);
}
```

К слову, если хотите перехватывать нажатие ESC не только в консоли, можно использовать функцию [GetAsyncKeyState()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) из Windows.h

```
for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
{
    int state = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
    if (state == 1 || state == -32767 && i == 27)
        exit(0);
}
```

---

[Коды клавиш](http://netcode.ru/cpp/?artID=234)